# Batch Processing while consuming blockingcollection

Tags: c#, blockingcollection

I have a blockingcollection which needs to be batch processed for 5 mins duration. Right now I am using `GetConsumingEnumerable()` but I don't want this instead I need to batch process.

```
var reqs = MessageFactory.NetApiRequestQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable(token).ToObservable();           

reqs.SubscribeOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance).Subscribe(x =>
{
});
```

Comment: Added language tag and corrected code indentation.

Comment: Since you are using Reactive Extension you can try to use throttle which allows the behavior you want. [Observable.Throttle msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229400%28v=vs.103%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)